# Why Is :fs.start_link/2 Undefined?

Tags: interop, elixir

I'm attempting to use the [fs](https://github.com/synrc/fs) library with Elixir.  Elixir 1.2.5 and fs 0.9.2 on Windows 10. I've added fs to my dependencies in my mix.exs and it seems to be there (see below) but for some reason I keep getting an error trying to run `:fs.start_link/2`

I start `iex -S mix` and everything loads fine.  I then try this: `:fs.known_events()` which returns: `[:created, :modified, :removed, :renamed, :undefined]` which is why I'm assuming that fs is getting loaded correctly.

But when I try `:fs.start_link(:fs_watcher, "/users/ocaten~1")` I get `** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function :fs.start_link/2`  I tried `:fs.start_link(:fs_watcher, '/users/ocaten~1')` as well (char list vs. string) and get the same error. I checked the source of fs and there's definitely a start_link/2 function and it's exported so I'm really stumped by this.

Any suggestions as to how I might proceed?

Comment: Check `:fs.module_info()` for smth interesting

Comment: I know the Erlang tag was removed and that's fine but I did add the Erlang tag deliberately.  fs is an Erlang lib and I was looking at the Erlang code to see if start_link/2 was defined.  I thought perhaps I was reading the Erlang source wrong--which is why I tagged it with Erlang.

Comment: @Lol4t0 I haven't tested but I believe Dogbert got it right--just that the source for fs doesn't match the hex package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `:fs.start_link/2` was added on [11 Nov 2015](https://github.com/synrc/fs/commit/1548007790352ac72b4dadfb9b092d0d23c8dbb8) while version 0.9.2 was released on [23 Apr 2015](https://hex.pm/packages/fs/0.9.2). There is no release on hex.pm after 0.9.2 so you'll have to depend on the Github version if you want to use `:fs.start_link/2`:

mix.exs:

```
defp deps do
  [{:fs, git: "https://github.com/synrc/fs"}]
end
```

Test:

```
iex(1)> :fs.start_link(:fs_watcher, "/tmp")
{:ok, #PID<0.168.0>}
```

Comment: Ok--that makes sense.  Thanks for that.  I was just stumped as to why I wasn't able to get that to work.

Comment: Tip: you should have searched in `deps/fs`. I did that first and was wondering where you had even seen `start_link/2` in `fs.erl`. :)